# Veikk stylus isn't detected

Tags: graphics-tablet, stylus

I'm using a Veikk A15 drawing tablet because my Monopiece tablet stopped working on Ubuntu 19.10.  While the touchpad and even the keys are detected Ubuntu thinks the stylus is a mouse which means there is no pressure sensitivity when I use it.  I tried testing the pen with both evtest and xinput test but no event occurs.  Then I visit this site:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507687/graphic-tablet-veikk-pressure-sensitivity-on-linux

When I tried to run this script (sudo ./combine_both.py /dev/input/event7) I get  sudo: ./combine_both.py: command not found

Comment: Shameless plug: [VEIKK Linux Driver](https://github.com/jlam55555/veikk-linux-driver) -- this driver started from that post

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo ./combine_both.py /dev/input/event7` is trying to execute the python file `combine_both.py`. You need to save the python script from the link as `combine_both.py` and then locate the directory from the terminal. From within the directory run the `chmod +x combine_both.py` command to let the shell know the file is executable. This should allow you to run `sudo ./combine_both.py /dev/input/event7`.